# Windows Phone Panorama templates missing from visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I've installed visual studio express 2013 for windows with update 2, and the windows phone 8.1 sdk. There is still no option to add a panorama page or panorama project. What am I missing? All I see is objects such as "blank page", "basic page" or "Content Dialog". I'm using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started the wrong project before installing update 2. As a result I couldn't add panorama pages. I started a new project after installing update 2, and the panorama project option was there. I can now add panorama pages too.

Answer (score 1):

With studio express 2013 for windows with update 2

It should be here

[image]

[Universal Windows Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/04/02/visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc-universal-projects-for-windows-and-windows-phone.aspx)

With Visual studio 2013 Ultimate

[image]

Comment: Are you really have _visual studio express 2013 for windows with update 2, and the windows phone 8.1 sdk_?

Comment: check the link i modified